# Huge increase in postgresql's CPU usage after upgrade to 10.3

Tags: postgresql

Sunday we upgraded our RDS instance from postgresql 9.6 to 10.3. After that, we started to see a way bigger CPU consumption.

[image]

I've checked and looks like the two versions have a few different defaults parameters. Anyone know which one could be the cause of the difference in CPU?

[image]

Comment: stats already gathered?..

Comment: yes. the database isn't that huge, about 300gb

Comment: so you chacked the plains and they dont seem to swith to nested loops after upgrade? and all other possible reasons?..

Comment: If your statistics are ok (`ANALYZE` has run), then use `pg_stat_statements` to see which queries are consuming your CPU. Come back with specific questions.